# Asymptotic complexity with a parameter between 0 and 1

Tags: asymptotics

I have an algorithm with running time depending on a parameter $ x \in (0, 1) $.

How is the asymptotic complexity of such algorithms typically analized?

In my particular case the running time approaches ∞ as x -> 1 but I don't know what I can say beyond that.

---

EDIT

More details about my particular algorithm:

The algorithm terminates when a given score `S` is reached (`S` is a parameter). On each iteration of the algorithm, `S` can either increase by 1 or be set to 0 (with probability `x`). I am looking to better understand the expected number of iterations as a function of `x`.

Comment: Can you describe your algorithm and its dependence on $x$ in more detail?

Comment: @zkutch I added more details to the question.

Comment: Running time is often a function of its inputs. You can approximate the mean (a function of $S$ and $x$) and worst case (infinite) complexities.